# Strange C# compiler behavior when using inheritance and overload

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Yesterday I saw strange C# compiler behavior when dealing with inheritance and overload resolution. Today I tried to reproduce it in new project and I was able to. You can see full experimental project using [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/mammadovadil/experiments.inheritanceandoverload/src/master/). But, basically I have two classes. `ExecuterBase` is as following:

```
public class ExecuterBase
{
    public virtual void Execute(Analytics analytics)
    {
        analytics?.Execute();
    }
}
```

And `Executer`which inherits `ExecuterBase` is as below:

```
public class Executer : ExecuterBase
{
    public void Experiment()
    {
        var analytics = new Analytics();
        Execute(analytics);
    }

    public void Execute<TNonAnalytics>(TNonAnalytics nonAnalytics)
        where TNonAnalytics : INonAnalytics
    {
        nonAnalytics?.Execute();
    }

    public override void Execute(Analytics analytics)
    {
        // some additional staff goes here
        base.Execute(analytics);
    }
}
```

`Analytics` and `INonAnalytics` are almost empty just for demonstration:

```
public class Analytics
{
    public void Execute()
    { }
}

public interface INonAnalytics
{
    void Execute();
}
```

`Analytics` doesn't implement `INonAnalytics`. 
The problem is that I get **compiler error** at `Execute(analytics);` line inside `Experiment` method.

> The type 'Experiments.InheritanceAndOverload.Analytics' cannot be used
>   as type parameter 'TNonAnalytics' in the generic type or method
>   'Executer.Execute(TNonAnalytics)'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from
>   'Experiments.InheritanceAndOverload.Analytics' to
>   'Experiments.InheritanceAndOverload.INonAnalytics'

Obviously it tries to use `public void Execute<TNonAnalytics>(TNonAnalytics nonAnalytics)` where it should use overrided method. Interestingly enough it compiles OK when you put all the methods inside same class. You can see that class - [SingleExecuter.cs](https://bitbucket.org/mammadovadil/experiments.inheritanceandoverload/src/master/src/Experiments.InheritanceAndOverload/Single/SingleExecuter.cs) - in the repository.

1. It compiles OK when I use `base.Execute(analytics);` instead, but I need override method, so it is not an option.
2. It compiles OK when I use `Execute(INonAnalytics nonAnalytics)` instead of `public void Execute<TNonAnalytics>(TNonAnalytics nonAnalytics)` - but in original project I have more than one type constraints and also I use generic type parameter inside this method, so it is also not an option.

Even if there is some workaround I want to learn **reason why compiler behaves like this** instead of this workaround. May be there is some C# language specifications that applies here and I miss them. I suspect it is a compiler bug.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: This is just about overload resolution, there are complex rules around how this works. When you have the generic method, the compiler will try to use it first, otherwise it will use the method from the base class.

Comment: @DavidG I understand, but when it doesn't match it should try to find matching method instead of giving me compiler error, don't you agree?

Comment: Not necessarily, the rules are far more complex than you might assume. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#overload-resolution

Comment: @DavidG thank you, I will read it, but before I read - does it answer why it works when I put all that methods in same class?

Comment: @HansPassant no, I have one Analytics type. You can easily clone the repository, it is very small

Comment: It would perhaps be worth referring to this post which describes something very close to your issue: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/ In short, constraints on generic type parameters are *not* considered when determining the overload to use, so the generic method is chosen as the better matching overload (since it can be made to match the parameters exactly), and then later in the process it fails when the constraints are validated.

Comment: @Iridium thank you for link, it seems very similar to my issue. But in my case it works when all the methods are in one class, so it is really confusing for me

Comment: Did you try to use Analytics declaration instead of var? I mean: Analytics analytics = new Analytics(); instead of using var?

Comment: @AdamJachocki it should not have any difference

Comment: I found duplicate questions. And you can read "Inheritance" section of https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Overloading for more info

Comment: @AdilMammadov It SHOULD not :)

Comment: @AdamJachocki I mean there is no difference :)